# Highcharts:Legend and title overlap pie chart when updating data

Tags: highcharts

I've encounted a problem when updating data of pie chart by clicking on a button - the legend and title overlap pie chart. But what's interesting is that when I resize the browser, for example, maximize the browser, position of title and legend go back normal.

Problem example is shown at http://jsfiddle.net/HmmeX/3/.

Data is updated by

```
$('button').click(function() {
 //       var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.setTitle({
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        });
        chart.series[0].setData(adata, true);/*update({
            data: adata});*/
    });
```

Comment: FYI: reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2261)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a bug to me.  You can work around it by adding `size : 300` to your pie options.

```
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        legend: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true,
                size:300
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: []
        }]
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xNmLd/

Comment: adjusting the margins of the chart and y offset of the legend work very well to fine tune placement